# Nth Fibonacci number in Go using recursion and concurrency

Tags: go, recursion, concurrency, fibonacci, goroutine

[The Java Code I'm attempting to translate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDfgN.png) I've been trying to implement this java method of getting the nth Fibonacci number in **Go** but I can't seem to get my code past the number Fibonacci number 35 before it crashes. This method **is** supposed to be very inefficient but not so inefficient that it doesn't complete.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Fibonacci struct {
    num    float64
    answer float64
}

func newFibonacci(n float64) *Fibonacci {

    f := new(Fibonacci)
    f.num = n
    c1 := make(chan float64)
    c2 := make(chan float64)

    if f.num <= 1 {
        f.answer = n
    } else {
        go func() {
            fib1 := newFibonacci(n - 1)
            c2 <- fib1.answer
        }()
        go func() {
            fib2 := newFibonacci(n - 2)
            c1 <- fib2.answer   
        }()

        f.answer = <-c2 + <-c1
    }
    close(c1)
    close(c2)

    return f
}

func main() {

    numbers := []float64{30, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40}
    for _, value := range numbers{
        start := time.Now()
        fmt.Println("getting the ", value, " fibonacci number")
        f := newFibonacci(value)
        fmt.Println(f.answer)
        end := time.Now()
        totalTime := end.Sub(start)
        fmt.Println("Fibonacci number: ", value, " took ", totalTime, "\n")
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a combinatorial explodion: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~gfb/csc104/2016W/Lectures/CSC104.2016W.Week-7.Lecture.Fibonacci.I.pdf

Comment: "supposed to be very efficient" and then "recursive fibonacci implementation", these two doesn't go together, period. An efficient fibonacci implementation uses a loop, and isn't recursive. The recursive variant is only good for one thing and that is teaching about the pitfalls of recursion.

Comment: "supposed to be very inefficient" and I am using this to teach the pitfalls. I'm hoping to implement a worker pool and limit the amount of workers to the number of available CPUs. I would just like to get this working to show the differences.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do the math behind how many goroutines you're actually launching.

Your first call spawns two goroutines.  Each of those spawn two further goroutines.  The total number of goroutines spawned will be `2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^n`.  While a lot of these will exit before you reach the number below, it's still a **lot** of goroutines.

[image: Sum]

Answer (score 1):

You program create exponential number of go routines. That comes with context switching latency. Try to run it for limited number of go routines. See following code where i run it for limited number of go routines:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Fibonacci struct {
    num    float64
    answer float64
}

type goRoutineManager struct {
    goRoutineCnt chan bool
}

func (g *goRoutineManager) Run(f func()) {
    select {
    case g.goRoutineCnt <- true:
        go func() {
            f()
            <-g.goRoutineCnt
        }()
    default:
        f()
    }
}

func NewGoRoutineManager(goRoutineLimit int) *goRoutineManager {
    return &goRoutineManager{
        goRoutineCnt: make(chan bool, goRoutineLimit),
    }
}

func newFibonacci(n float64, gm *goRoutineManager) *Fibonacci {

    f := new(Fibonacci)
    f.num = n
    c1 := make(chan float64, 1)
    c2 := make(chan float64, 1)

    if f.num <= 1 {
        f.answer = n
    } else {

        gm.Run(func() {
            fib1 := newFibonacci(n-1, gm)
            c2 <- fib1.answer
        })

        gm.Run(func() {
            fib2 := newFibonacci(n-2, gm)
            c1 <- fib2.answer
        })

        f.answer = <-c2 + <-c1
    }
    close(c1)
    close(c2)

    return f
}

func main() {

    numbers := []float64{30, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40} //{30, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40}
    for _, value := range numbers {
        start := time.Now()
        fmt.Println("getting the ", value, " fibonacci number")

        gm := NewGoRoutineManager(3)

        f := newFibonacci(value, gm)
        fmt.Println(f.answer)

        end := time.Now()
        totalTime := end.Sub(start)
        fmt.Println("Fibonacci number: ", value, " took ", totalTime, "\n")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

cause you are creating too many channels.Try to use the trivial algorithm when the problem is relatively small.
the following program works when n==45,I guess it will also crash when n is around 65.Trivial fib is acctually quite a hard problem to run in parallel properlly.

```
func fib(n int) int {
    if n < 2 {
        return 1
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
}

func fibP(n int) int {
    //base case
    if n < 25 {
        return fib(n)
    }
    fib2chan := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        fib2chan <- fibP(n - 2)
    }()
    return fibP(n-1) + <-fib2chan
}
```